# How to sort based on values of a key-value pair using a Priority-Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a map of values based on key-value pairs.
e.g
[{1,2},{2,5},{3,4},{4,1}]

How can I sort them on the basis of the values using a priority queue?

Required output:
[{4,1}->{1,2}->{3,4}->{2,5}]

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service for writing code. Please share the code you have tried and what's not working

Answer (score -1):

You need to override method `compareTo` in object class you add to priority queue:
This is Employee class with two fields is id and salary.
I'm use id as key and salary as value. Then i will sort it by value (salary)

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee employee) {
    if(this.getSalary() > employee.getSalary()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.getSalary() < employee.getSalary()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```